# How do I add a second if for a new validation?

Tags: javascript

I want to do a second validation with these variables. But how should it be for the 2 validations to be carried out

```
detail.price<detail.price2

var art;

me.arrayDetails.map(function(x){
    if (x.cantidad>x.stock){
        art = x.articulo + " con stock insuficiente";
        me.errorMostrarMsjVenta.push(art);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just add another `if` or `else if`, depending on whether it's independent of or exclusive of the first check.

Comment: BTW, there's no reason to declare `art` outside the function. It should be a local variable.